# prerequisites to download audio files in iOS app

Tags: ios, audio

I'm going to build an iOS application in which you can download audio files and listen to them in offline mode. so far I found out the following process can be done to build the app: creating an xml file with list of audio files on the server and fetch xml with ASIHTTPRequest and parse it into the app (well I still have problem doing this, but my question is something else!)

Before start coding I want to know

1. what is the right data format for audio files to choose (I know that .mp3, .aac, .m4a, .mp4, .3gp, CAF, MPEG, WAVE, NeXT,... could be used), but I need to know if there is a best format to choose to have better functionality in the app.
2. is there special consideration that I should take about 3G and wifi connection to download files( I need to know about limitations or techniques for implementing them)

I ask these questions to be able to estimate the time for creating the app regarding techniques that I should use.

Comment: FYI `ASIHTTPRequest` stopped development a while back now. For new projects, you should use AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, actually I've read that they're using AFNetworking instead, but since I found more documents about ASIHTTPRequest, I thought maybe I can use it, I actually tried NSURLConnection as well, but as I said after a while I decided to know more about techniques which I asked about, before start coding